# Trouble with assigning folder permissions with powershell

Tags: powershell, permissions, directory

I would like this powershell script to create a new directory, and add/assign permissions with a group.

The group is adding, but the permissions are not showing under Properties on the Security tab. If going to Advances security the permissions do show there.

Also, the parent folder permissions are not being removed from the new child folder as desired.

```
$groups = "DOMAIN\GROUP"
$Perm = "MODIFY"
$Permission = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights] $Perm
$AllInherit = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags] "None"
$AllPropagation = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags] "InheritOnly"
$path = "c:\temp\test"
new-item -path $path -itemtype directory -force
$group = $groups
$GetACL = Get-Acl $Path
$Access = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount ($group)
$AccessRule = New-Object system.security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Access, $perm, $AllInherit, $Allpropagation, "Allow")
$GetACL.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
SET-ACL -PATH $path $getacl
```

Comment: In addition, the InheritOnly propagation is not being properly set.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function I wrote for a similar purpose:

```
function Add-AclEntry {
    # Adds a new entry to the specified file system object ACL. For
    # folders the new permissions are applied recursively.
    # Returns: null.
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$sPath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        # Access group (full notation).
        [String]$sGroup,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        # List of access rights, comma separated.
        [String]$sRights,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [ValidateSet("Allow", "Deny")]
        [String]$sType = "Allow"
    )

    $cRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]$sRights
    $oType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::$sType
    $oGroup = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($sGroup)

    # Inheritance flags: full inheritance.
    if ((Get-Item $sPath).PSIsContainer) {
        $oInheritanceFlags = (`
             [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ObjectInherit `
        -bor [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ContainerInherit)
    } else {
        $oInheritanceFlags = `
            [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::None
    }
    $oPropagationFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None

    # Creating access control entry and adding it to the ACL.
    $oAce = New-Object `
        -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule `
        ($oGroup, $cRights, $oInheritanceFlags, $oPropagationFlags, $oType)
    $oAcl = Get-Acl -Path $sPath
    $oAcl.AddAccessRule($oAce)
    Set-Acl -Path $sPath -AclObject $oAcl

    return $null
}
```

Example usage (adding `Modify` permissions for `Authenticated Users` group):

```
$sGroup = "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users"
$sRights = "Delete, Read, Traverse, Write"
Add-AclEntry -sPath $sFolder -sGroup $sGroup -sRights $sRights
```

Hope that helps.